# Caffe: How do you print a weighted loss for the testing layer?

Tags: caffe

My current Caffe output looks like this:

```
Iteration 1000, Testing net (#0)
Test net output #0: accuracy_1 = 0.337018
Test net output #1: accuracy_2 = 0.3397
Test net output #2: accuracy_3 = 0.360761
Test net output #3: loss_1 = 2.08132 (* 1 = 2.08132 loss)
Test net output #4: loss_2 = 2.03755 (* 1 = 2.03755 loss)
Test net output #5: loss_3 = 1.91984 (* 1 = 1.91984 loss)

Iteration 1000, loss = 3.87841
Train net output #0: loss_1 = 1.26657 (* 1 = 1.26657 loss)
Train net output #1: loss_2 = 1.40096 (* 1 = 1.40096 loss)
Train net output #2: loss_3 = 1.21088 (* 1 = 1.21088 loss)
```

The training iteration prints out the correct weighted loss (aka "loss = 3.87841"), while the testing iteration simply says "Testing net (#0)". How do I get the testing iteration to also print out the correct weighted loss? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is your weighted loss; but it is the average_loss of training smoothed across iterations.

You may want to check the average_loss field here:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solver.cpp#L190-L221

Share your loss and accuracy layers to receive a more detailed answer.